# How to access data inside class

Tags: flutter, timestamp

I'm trying to convert a timestamp I get from a network call and display it as regular time and date in my app. But I cant access the "int timestamp" from its class.

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

int timeInMillis = **timestamp**; // I'm trying to get the timestamp here !!

var date = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(timeInMillis);
var formattedDate = DateFormat('HH:mm - dd.MM.yyyy').format(date);


class Posts {

  final String result;
  final int timestamp;
  final String time;

  Posts({this.timestamp, this.result, this.time});

  factory Posts.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Posts(

      result: json['result'],
      timestamp: json['timestamp'],
      time: formattedDate,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is that network call?

Comment: It is in another file: Network.dart

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the value from json using `int.parse('1610515846')`

```html
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

int timeInMillis = **timestamp**; // I'm trying to get the timestamp here !!

var date = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(timeInMillis);
var formattedDate = DateFormat('HH:mm - dd.MM.yyyy').format(date);


class Posts {

  final String result;
  final int timestamp;
  final String time;

  Posts({this.timestamp, this.result, this.time});

  factory Posts.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Posts(

      result: json['result'],
      timestamp: int.parse(json['timestamp']),
      time: formattedDate,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Where do you get the idea that the problem is there? My understanding of the question did not lead me to believe the OP was having trouble with their `fromJson` constructor. How do you know that `json['timestamp']` is a String?

Comment: This is the reply from my web request:{"result":"OK","timestamp":1610545978787}, I want to change the timestamp to a regular time/date before displaying it on my screen.  I can only display it raw like this.  I still cant figure out how to parse the timestamp to the top of the code where it is transformed.